# Saying $\forall A \in SO(3) \implies \exists X \in \mathfrak{so}(3)$ such that $A = \mathrm{exp}(X)$

Tags: exponential-function, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose we have a general Lie group $G$ and it's corresponding Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. I think that it is true that for all $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ we have $\mathrm{exp}(X) \in G$.

However, the converse is not true because I don't think $\mathrm{exp}$ will cover all of $G$. Meaning, if I hand you $g \in G$, you cannot tell me with certainty that there exists some $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ such that $\exp(X) = g$ (in general).

I think though, that $SO(3)$ $does$ have this converse property. That is to say I think it is true that $\forall A \in SO(3)$, $\exists X \in \mathfrak{so}(3)$ such that $A = \mathrm{exp}(X)$.

First of all, am I right in thinking this? Physical intuition say that it is true.

Secondly, if it is true is there some way to prove this? Or is there some kind of theorem about this result?

Comment: The corresponding statement is true for every compact, connected Lie group, not just $SO(3)$. **Hint** On any such group, we can construct a bi-invariant metric, and then the two available notions of the exponential map coincide. The analogous statement does not hold for all connected Lie groups.

Comment: I answered this question in my answer to one of your previous questions. I even gave an explicit formula for how to find the $X$ corresponding to a given rotation.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163395/a-mapping-phi-mathfrakso3-to-mathbbr3-such-that-phigxg-1

Comment: To prove the formula, I suggest going to a coordinate frame in which the axis of rotation is aligned with one of your coordinate axes.

Comment: An example of a Lie group where this fails is $O(3)$, which has two disconnected components (det = +1 and det = -1).

Comment: Yes, this is true, and the proof is very straightforward: every element of $SO(3)$ is a rotation about some axis, hence is a member of a one-parameter family given by all rotations about that axis. Every one-parameter family is of the form $\exp (tX)$ for some $X \in \mathfrak{g}$: this is a general property of the exponential map.